# dplyr Mutate Creating Matrix Instead of Vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am creating a new column that looks at conditions in my data frame and alerts me whether an issue needs to be investigated or monitored. The code to add the column looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate("Status" = 
           ifelse(apply(.[2:7], 1, sum) > 0 & .[8] > 0, "Investigate", 
                  "Monitor"
                  )
         )
```

If I run the command `class(df$Status)` on this newly generated column the class is listed as 'matrix'. What? Why isn't it listed as 'character'. 
If I look at the structure of my data frame there's some oddity that may be the key, but I don't understand why. Notice that the first columns listed simply look like intergers, then the third column listed, which is the same data, has all this 'attr' phrasing. What is going on?

```
 $ 2017-08 : int  NA 1 NA 1 1 2 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ 2017-09 : int  NA NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ 2017-10 : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr "Material"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 34
  ..$ : int 0
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int 3
  ..$ : int 4
...continued...
 - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 1
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  34 obs. of  1 variable:
```

I grouped variables earlier and sometimes ungrouping magically helps. In addition I often have to convert tibbles back to data frames to get other routines to work in my code. This may or may not be related.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of df? where does it come from?

Comment: We can recreate a similar data set from mtcars and get the same issue. I'll paste the code below, and notice if you do a **str(mtcars.spread)** the '8' cylinder integer has this same weird issue. Here's the code:         `mtcars.df <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(disp, cyl) %>% 
  summarise(Qty = n())`
 and here's the rest of it 
`mtcars.spread <- mtcars.df %>% 
  spread(cyl, Qty)`

Comment: I'm getting a vector from that: `is.vector(mtcars.spread$'8')` - `TRUE`

Comment: Yeah that's true. Can you go ahead and do a `str(mtcars.spread)` after the other two commands and let me know your thoughts on the weird description of the '8' variable? My df data frame is hard to recreate. I'll see what I can do to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dplyr Group - Do I need to then Ungroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824109/dplyr-group-do-i-need-to-then-ungroup)

Comment: Isn't this essentially coming down to the same issue you have raised in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824109/dplyr-group-do-i-need-to-then-ungroup)?

Comment: I'm speculating the root cause is grouping without an ungroup but I really don't have much of a clue. If that is the root cause I can close out this one. If it's not I'll need to continue investigating until I find an answer I can put down below.