# dplyr Group - Do I need to then Ungroup

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's some simple code utilizing dplyr to group and spread data from the mtcars data set.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars.df <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(disp, cyl) %>% 
  summarise(Qty = n())

mtcars.spread <- mtcars.df %>% 
  spread(cyl, Qty)

str(mtcars.spread)
```

When you look at the structure of the 'mtcars.spread' tibble you'll notice the '4' and '6' cylinder variable are listed as integers, while the '8' cylinder variable has all this babble

> - attr(*, "vars")= chr "disp"
> - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
> - attr(*, "indices")=List of 27

attached to it. Where did I go wrong? Am I supposed to ungroup along the way after using the group_by command?

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 27 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ disp: num  71.1 75.7 78.7 79 95.1 ...
 $ 4   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ 6   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ 8   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr "disp"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 27
  ..$ : int 0
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int 3
  ..$ : int 4
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int 6
  ..$ : int 7
  ..$ : int 8
  ..$ : int 9
  ..$ : int 10
  ..$ : int 11
  ..$ : int 12
  ..$ : int 13
  ..$ : int 14
  ..$ : int 15
  ..$ : int 16
  ..$ : int 17
  ..$ : int 18
  ..$ : int 19
  ..$ : int 20
  ..$ : int 21
  ..$ : int 22
  ..$ : int 23
  ..$ : int 24
  ..$ : int 25
  ..$ : int 26
 - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 1
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  27 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ disp: num  71.1 75.7 78.7 79 95.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "disp"
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

Comment: Those attributes are related to the class `grouped_df`, if you `ungroup` after your `summarise` then those attributes will fall away. It can be an issue at times when a subsequent function behaves differently grouped or ungrouped, but in your example, the data itself would be unchanged either way.

Comment: I agree with @KevinArseneau.  Leaving a data frame grouped introduces an unnecessary dependency with later code.  What code consume the dataset, it has to assume (a) that it's group, and (b) how it's grouped.  My team always tries to leave a data frame in its resting/ungrouped state.  As soon as possible in the magrittr chain --certainly before the chain concludes.